# How to enumerate Edge tabs to close one of them?

Tags: javascript, windows, microsoft-edge

I need to close a tab identified by its title (page title) in Edge.
Currently this url is opened in Firefox, it's possible to close it with a javascript window.close() command upon receipt of a notification by a websocket connection.
Now I have to use Edge and continue to be able to close this page on request but the window.close() command no longer works and i get the message "Scripts may close only the windows thare are opened by them". However, I noticed that on some PCs the command is accepted but don't know why.

- Is it possible to configure Edge to still accept this command (settings / GPO / ...)?
- Which other method can i use to do it: C++ / Javascript / ...

The solution must work on a PC where you do not have PC administration rights and certain Windows and Edge settings are controlled by the company (GPO).

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you open and close Edge so that we can have a better understanding of your demands? For example, how do you open Edge, manually or programmatically?